# Reputation not showing in search

Tags: support, reputation, users

I searched for my friend 'Ralph Lavelle' on SO so I can compare reputation.

In the search it always shows 0 for his reputation even though its ~1000

https://stackoverflow.com/users/48791/ralph-lavelle

Comment: it shows 1078 rep?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking at his rep for this week only. Click on the `[all]` link to see his full rep.

[image]

Comment: ahh did not see those buttons to the side, my bad

Comment: @DanielPowell don't worry, you're not the first to be caught out by that.

Comment: @ShawnChin - Hmm...perhaps the default is wrong? Do most people expect to see overall rep?

Comment: @cdeszaq I vaguely recall seeing a meta post discussing that but I can't find it anymore. Can't remember what the verdict was.

Comment: ... although I do see some sense in using the "week" view as a default - Since the results are sorted by rep, a "week" view will return recently active users first which is arguably a sensible metric for determining relevance.

Answer (score 2):

That's the rep earned for the week.

[image]

---

Change it to all and you'll see the total rep earned.

[image]

Comment: You have missed out on all of the "hand drawn circles" upvotes =)

Comment: And the hand-drawn-text upvotes

Comment: hah, true :))))